# What equipment do I need to reprogram an old garage opener remote?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, programming, hardware

I recently took an interest into hardware programming, and instead of buying something like an arduino I was wondering if I can reprogram the microcontrollers on old garage remotes or tv remotes. I don't want to anything fancy, just want to test some things. If I can do that what equipment would I need?

Comment: Could you add more details about your specific hardware? What would you like to do with these remotes?

Comment: It really depends on hardware you want to program.

Comment: I would expect that going with an Arduino would be much more satisfying to start out. There is a lot more support by the Arduino community with lots of information available. And there are kits available with parts along with documentation. I have taken apart two devices, an automated coffee pot and a cordless phone, just to see what was in there. The pot was more understandable than the much more complex phone. I could find some documentation on parts but in the end I have found working with an Arduino and a kit more fruitful.

Comment: I was thinking of sending specific binary messages, instead of the garage code. All I know is that the remote brand is BFT and in the back it has 5 pin entrances, I presume it is used to program the remote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably that is not possible.

- There will not be a USB connection.
- Even if you can find the microcontroller, you need to hard-solder the pins to be able to reprogram it.
- If you are able to find a way to program it, you have to reverse-engineer the circuit to see what you can do.
- Not all components might be identifiable (because they are hidden or even texts removed).

However, if you can find a way to access the pins to program, to solder wires to it, to see how the circuit is laid out, than it should be possible. Also note, that you are stuck to the hardware already present (unless you can add hardware yourself).

Update:

See also comments below (so check if you really have a microcontroller or a dedicated flashed all-in-one-chip).

Another problem is that for e.g. Arduino you can find easily a workable IDE. For a not so known brand, it might be hard to set up the IDE, find documentation, user support etc.

Comment: The micro-controller for many small and single purpose devices are flashed and can not be changed.

Comment: @RichardChambers Does that mean that those are never e.g. STM32s, ATMega etc chips? (since I thought you always can put them in a mode to program them).

Comment: Especially ones made by the millions in china

Comment: In the remote there are 5 pins in the back, with the cap on, I assume that is where i reprogram the controller

Comment: What is the microcontroller brand/model?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers For simple devices like these, it's often not even a microcontroller, but something like an all-in-one chip like the PT2264 which is hard wired internally. The HCS301 is also popular.

Comment: I was assuming the questioner was talking (and checked) it was a microcontroller (so based my answer on that).

Comment: I think it has a microcontroller because it has rolling code, and all It says is the brand which is BFT

Comment: But are you saying that for a different controller I'm going to need different equipment?

Comment: Well, I mean if you don't know the exact microcontroller, it will be really hard to write code for, because even within one brand there can be a lot of differences (supportable hardware).

Comment: @RodrigoPina the HCS301, for example, is not a microcontroller and does use a rolling code.

Comment: They aren't usually even flashed, they use mask ROM, i.e. they are fabbed with the program hard-wired in.

Comment: For anyone interested in what is a rolling code, [Rolling Code Explanation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85657/rolling-code-explanation) as well as [How does a rolling code work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/how-does-a-rolling-code-work).